# What methods are used to determine acceptable loss levels for autoencoders?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, autoencoder

I've been looking at autoencoders for disparate uses such as dimension reduction, blurring or sharpening images and data denoising.

What methods are used to determine acceptable loss levels for autoencoders?

Answer (score 1):

Acceptable loss levels depend on the specific domain, dataset, and model.

Loss levels can be compared within model (e.g., training loss by epoch) or across models (e.g., autoencoders with different levels of compression).

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @Brian but it seems that you are looking for some common function names that goes hand in hand for Auto encoder training.

Assume your output is of dimension (n,1) so you will calculate loss individually for every node (total n nodes) and then aggregate them by something trivial like sum or avg. Now, this loss per node can be very selective based on the problem. For a general dimension reduction approach, you can use mse loss per node.

While a typical image denoising case can be removing some pattern or background, so your output will be a feature map with m X n size (preferably same as input size) where every pixel will be either 1 or 0 (that is to be removed or not). In such case, you will need cross entropy loss for every pixel.

Please nudge if more clarification needed.

Answer (score 1):

So the question address what methods can we use to assess whether (validation) loss for an auto-encoder is appropriate.

As @Brian has alluded to, loss levels are dependent on the task. **To determine an appropriate loss value for a given task, we usually use a dummy / baseline model as point of comparison against more sophisticated model architectures or more fine-tuned model hyperparameters.**

Therefore, I would recommend you determine what would be an appropriate baseline (typically a simpler, less complex model) and then find the validation loss for this model and then use this value to compare other validation losses for other models of interest.